# Integrating using series and squeeze theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

The integral I want to solve is:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t} dt$$

By substitution:

$$ -t =u$$

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ 1-e^t}{t} dt$$

Maclaurin expanding the numerator,

$$ \int_0^{\infty}  - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{t^{k-1} }{k!}dt$$

Integrating termwise:

$$ -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ t^k}{k k!} \biggm|_0^{\infty}$$

Now the tricky part is upper bound.. I'm thinking of using squeeze to figure out limit. My attempt is as follows:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ t^k}{ k!}  \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ t^k}{k k!}  \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ t^k}{(k+1)!} $$

This doesn't seem to work.. any hints?

Comment: To my knowledge $\int_0^\infty (1/x) dx $ diverges

Comment: Very divergent integral, as $e^{-t}\to\infty$ rather quickly as $t\to -\infty$.

Comment: You probably want to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{\color{red}{-}t}}{t}\,dt$$This integral diverges.

Comment: Could limit comparison work here if my initial comment is divergent and since $1/x$ is above all x from 0 to infinty then both series diverge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the substitution $-t=u$ we have $$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t} dt$$
$$=\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{1-e^{u}}{u}du=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}dt$$

and $\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}\geq1$ for all $t>0$ (where $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1)$, which follows from Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: Are you saying it's divergent?

Comment: Yes it diverges.